# when touches outside the tableview.How to dismiss the tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, touch-event

How to dismiss the tableview when we click on the view?i am using the touch began method.but its not working?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"touches began");
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
if(touch.view!=myTableView){
   myTableview.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

how to disable the table when we click on view.i am having three tableviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**ViewDidLoad**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handelGesture:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

**ActionMethod**

```
- (void) handelGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
    {
        myTableview.hidden = YES;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it is helps you please vote up
thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code it working if you modified for your requirement Thanks

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
         NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
        for (id objects in subviews) {
            if ([objects isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                UITextField *theTextField = objects;
                if ([objects isFirstResponder]) {
                    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```